# What happens when different object files use different malloc implementations

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a couple of questions.

1. Suppose a program is compiled using 2 object files. Each uses malloc and free in most of their functions. But these object files were generated at different times and happen to be using different malloc implementations. Let's say the implementations share variable names and function names. **Will the program work fine or not? Why?**
2. If a program has object file 1 and 2, code from object file 1 call malloc and allocates some memory then frees it. Now code from object file 2 calls malloc. **Can it use the memory that was freed? How does it work underneath?**

Answer (score 4):

Trying to provide a useful answer, even though it's far from complete.

Part 1.

- First, it's hard enough to *link* the program with two implementations of malloc sharing function names: duplicate definitions usually cause linker errors. I can see how we manage to do it using GNU binutils, and there probably are some equivalent tricks for other toolchains. For the rest of the answer, let's assume we managed to link two implementations successfully. (It's usually a *good* thing that you get linker errors instead of mixing two implementations, possibly even introducing malloc/free asymmetry which has almost no chance to work).
- Let's also assume that memory allocated with one particular implementation is always freed using `free` from the same implementation. Otherwise, it's virtually guaranteed to fail.
- Two implementations may work together, or they may interfere, depending on how they request more memory from the OS when their local heaps run out of space. MS Windows has a *system* interface for managing heaps, and two different `malloc`s are likely to be built on top of it; then nothing prevents them from working together. Implementations requesting memory with `sbrk`-like call will work together if they're both ready that *someone else* will request `sbrk` increase independently of `malloc`. I'd expect that malloc from glibc won't fail here, but I'm not really sure.

Part 2.

If the implementation used by object 1 is able to return memory to OS, memory can be reused by the implementation called by object 2. That is, memory reuse may happen but it's less likely than when a single implementation is used.

The possibility of returning memory to OS depends on malloc/free implementation, and may also depend on allocated chunk size and various system settings. For example, glibc uses anonymous `mmap` for large chunks of memory, and *these* chunks are unmapped when freed.